# Tooltip not showing when hovering

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

A simple piece of code.  I notice that when I hover over a '*', the tooltip doesn't show.

Are Tooltips working in Internet Explorer 10?

Code:

```
<p>Username:<asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UsernameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="Your Username is Required" ControlToValidate="UsernameTextBox" 
     Text="*">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UsernameRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please only use letters and numbers with no spaces." 
     ControlToValidate="UsernameTextBox" Text="*" 
     ToolTip="Please only use letters and numbers with no spaces." 
     ValidationExpression="\w{6,14}">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Regards,

Comment: Typically a number of validation messages are displayed in a ValidationSummary. I believe a * character tells the validator to expect a summary control.

Comment: Is this an issue with IE10 or it doesn't show the tooltip in any browser?

Comment: Try right clicking on page, and then move the mouse again
on *

also try to use double star ** as it might be the case that the mouse pointer is not properly placed at single *

Comment: I just tried to view it in Chrome, no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with your code .It's working fine for both IE10 and chrome browser. May be you messed up with RegularExpressionValidator Error message and RequiredFieldValidator Error message

Comment: you've seen my error messages above.  If you worked my code, you see they work.

Comment: Yes i have worked on your code and I have seen that tool tip message while hover on that "*"